# .mesh file "ref" var explanation

Tags: mesh, cgal

I am trying to understand the .mesh files, usually generated for mesh visualization with `Medit`.

The documentation is [here](http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/frey/logiciels/Docmedit.dir/index.html), but it is in french.

The thing I understand is that after every line describing and object in the file (vertex, triangle, tetrahedra, etc.) it comes a `ref` variable, that in the examples files I have, they usually are 0,1,2,3 and I don't understand what is their purpose.

Can somebody please explain this?

You can get an .mesh example [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23507925/out.mesh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each reference corresponds to a color in Medit. The colors are arbitrary, and can be changed in Medit (using the GUI or changing a configuration file).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand medit, I am using the linux version, so where can I see this color table or access GUI, or the configuration file?

Comment: If I remember well, there are color options in the menu that is accessible using the right click. And to modify a color, you must first select a triangle using shift-left-click .

Answer (score 2):

The **reference** values in the Mesh file refers to a **color** index. Maybe the program uses this to display the vertices, triangles and tetrahedra with certain colors. You can ignore this value for all practical purposes.

Comment: But don't you need to specify a color table?, I mean, this values can be color, but which colors?